# XML parsing with XPath. C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have some questions, maybe stupid question.

I have this url:
[http://flibusta.net/opds/opensearch?searchTerm=Тол&searchType=books](http://flibusta.net/opds/opensearch?searchTerm=%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB&searchType=books)

and I want to parse the response like this:

```
string search_link = "http://flibusta.net/opds/opensearch?searchTerm=Тол&searchType=books";

_document = new XPathDocument(search_link);

XPathNavigator navigator = _document.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("/feed/title");

while (nodes.MoveNext())
{
        XPathNavigator currentNavigator = nodes.Current;
        string title = currentNavigator.Value;
        Trace.WriteLine(title);
}
```

But nodes returns zero result. Can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Pavel.

Comment: Are those nodes in a namespace, if so you need to specify it in teh select argument e.g. navigator.Select("/myns:feed/myns:title");

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to be working, and chances are, it won't continue to work for as long as this question will exist on stack overflow, so, maybe if you could just show a small example of the XML you are hoping to parse in your actual question, it would be helpful.

Comment: 1) No the are not in any namespace.

Comment: 2) sorry, but link works good. But takes long time to load (Bad servers maybe :). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget about XML without namespaces. Try the following example, it works fine for me:

```
var document = new XPathDocument("http://flibusta.net/opds/opensearch?searchTerm=%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB&searchType=books");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("/atom:feed/atom:title", ns);

while (nodes.MoveNext())
{
        XPathNavigator currentNavigator = nodes.Current;
        string title = currentNavigator.Value;
        Trace.WriteLine(title);
}
```

Comment: Looks like the OP wasn't declaring his namespaces or passing the NamespaceManager into `Select(...)`